# Send email with HTML table in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Can some please help me with code for below scenario inn PowerShell.

I have data in my pipe delimited file like below.

```
File1.txt|Error1
File2.txt|Error2
```

Need to send email with table in below format.

```
FileName    Error type
File1   Error1
File2   Error2
```

I'm able to create the table in the email, but unable to pass the data into columns in table.

Comment: Please supply an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @PalleDue to have that MCVE expand automatically enclose it in square brackets \[mcve\] --> [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I would create an HTML table to embed in the email:

```
$HtmlTable = Import-Csv $PipeDelimitedFileName -Delimiter '|' -Header 'FileName','Error type' |
    ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
```

If you *must* have tab delimited text with a header, then I'd do it like this:

```
$TabTable = Import-Csv $PipeDelimitedFileName -Delimiter '|' -Header 'FileName','Error type' |
    ForEach-Object {
        "{0}`t{1}" -f $_.FileName, $_.'Error type'
    } -Begin { "{0}`t{1}" -f 'FileName','Error type' }
```

If input your file already has headers, then remove the `-Header 'FileName','Error type'` parameter.

Comment: can we get table borders and color for headers with this command?

Comment: @SureshBabu You can [include CSS](https://foxdeploy.com/2014/05/23/using-html-formatting-to-create-useful-webpage-reports-from-powershell/) if you like.  Conditional formatting is more complicated.  There's many tutorials online if you search.